# How to store ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> with Parcelable interface between Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I want to store `ArrayList<ArrayList<Transports>> arrayListsTransportsForAllStops` between activities. Class Transport implements Parcelable. But when i try to make

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("transports",arrayListsTransportsForAllStops);
```

My environmrnt get error:

[image]

And how to get this data back from intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through  `ArrayList<Transports>` objects in its enclosing **ArrayList** and for each of this `ArrayList<Transports>` objects you should use **putParcelableArrayListExtra** separately using different **keys** for each of them.

Comment: Well the API is leaving you with no choice. Consider what your goal is and make your mind up whether you should do this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want put parcelable to intent just add:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("transports", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) arrayListsTransportsForAllStops);
```

To get this in next activity:

```
Intent data = getIntent();
List <Transports> result = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("transports");
```

Comment: But  I want to get ArrayList<ArrayList<Transports>> instead List <Transports>

Comment: Maybe you have any ideas how to make it?

Comment: Error:(204, 100) error: inconvertible types
required: ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>
found:    ArrayList<ArrayList<Transports>> I get this exception when I try tu put data to intent